# Variance of Kinetic Energy Operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators

I am asked to calculate the variance of the kinetic energy in the ground state of the harmonic oscillator.  That requires $\langle T^2\rangle$.  This is the same as $\langle p^4\rangle$.  My question is do I have to go about and calculate
$$\langle 0|(a-a^\dagger)^4|0\rangle$$
Or is there a shortcut.

Comment: Evaluating the expression you show probably isn't as hard as you think it is. There are really only two terms out of the sixteen you need to calculate once you realize the others give you zero.

Answer (score 1):

We know how the creation operator acts on the vacuum, i.e.

$$(a^{\dagger})^n \lvert0\rangle =\sqrt{n!}\lvert n \rangle$$

where we use the notation $\lvert n \rangle$ to signify the state such that $\langle x \lvert n \rangle = \psi_n(x)$, i.e. the $n$th energy level of the harmonic oscillator. The annihilation operator kills the vacuum. Therefore the expression,

$$\langle 0 \lvert (a-a^{\dagger})^4\lvert0\rangle $$

only receives contributions from two terms which do not end up being zero due to the annihilation operators. An example of a term:

$$\langle 0 \lvert (a^{\dagger})^4 \rvert 0 \rangle =\sqrt{24} \langle 0 \lvert  4 \rangle=\sqrt{24} \int \mathrm{d}x \, \langle 0 \lvert x \rangle \langle x \rvert 4 \rangle= \sqrt{24}\int \mathrm{d}x \, \psi^{\dagger}_0(x) \psi_4(x)$$

where in obtaining the integral we have inserted the standard identity operator,

$$\mathbb{I} = \int \mathrm{d}x \, \lvert x \rangle \langle x \rvert$$